# Freeipa client on Ubuntu.

Tags: ldap

Does anyone have a good guide to get freeipa client installed and running on Ubuntu 13.04?

Just so I head off everyone up front, yes I know freeipa-client is a package, yes I know it has the ipa-client-install in it, yes I know the documentation is on freeipa.org.

With that said, the package does not install all the packages that are needed, the script barely rarely runs to completion and if it does, it doesn't work, and the documents for a manual install just flat out don't work.  This is the 3rd Ubuntu machine I have installed it on and not a single one have come online the same way.  This third one is a 13.04 machine and its just flat out refusing to work.  Does anyone have a guide?

Comment: http://www.linuxforums.org/articles/how-to-install-freeipa-client-2-1-4-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-_1855.html

Comment: Check out this PPA: apt-add-repository ppa:freeipa/ppa The guy who maintains it says that it should work with raring . . .

Answer (score 5):

This is what I do in Ubuntu [12.04](/questions/tagged/12.04) for a [freeipa](/questions/tagged/freeipa) server 3.0.0

- Install repos for sssd and freeipa-client

  ```
  sudo -E apt-add-repository http://ppa.launchpad.net/freeipa/ppa/ubuntu
  sudo -E apt-add-repository http://ppa.launchpad.net/sssd/updates/ubuntu
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade
  ```
- Update or verify fqdn in /etc/hosts, you should have a line like this:

  ```
  127.0.1.1 hostname.freeipa-domain-name hostname
  ```
- Verify that your /etc/resolv.conf has a correct configuration and it is able to resolve freeipa generated entries for that domain, example:

  ```
  dig freeipa.generated.entry
  ```
- Install necessary packages

  ```
  sudo apt-get install openssh-server freeipa-client sssd
  ```
- Remove default configuration file

  ```
  sudo rm /etc/ipa/default.conf
  ```
- Create this folders or the script won't work

  ```
  sudo mkdir /var/run/ipa
  sudo mkdir -p /etc/pki/nssdb
  ```
- Verify that you have a woking ntp client (configure /etc/ntp.conf)

  ```
  ntpq -pn
  ```
- Backup and revert reported version of ipapython so keys will upload

  ```
  sudo cp /usr/share/pyshared/ipapython/version.py /usr/share/pyshared/ipapython/version.py.bak

  sudo sed -i "s/API_VERSION=.*/API_VERSION=u'2.49'/g" /usr/share/pyshared/ipapython/version.py
  ```
- Make --mkhomedir functional

  ```
  sudo bash -c "cat > /usr/share/pam-configs/mkhomedir" <<EOF
  Name: activate mkhomedir
  Default: yes
  Priority: 900
  Session-Type: Additional
  Session:
          required                        pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0022 skel=/etc/skel
  EOF

  sudo pam-auth-update
  ```
- Finally, install client as root and answer installer questions

  ```
  sudo su -
  ipa-client-install -N --hostname hostname.freeipa-domain-name --mkhomedir
  ```
- Restart sssd or reboot

  ```
  /etc/init.d/sssd restart
  ```
- ssh to that machine with a freeipa user so the home directory will be created

  ```
  ssh freeipauser@hostname.freeipa-domain-name
  ```

Comment: The mkhomedir instructions here are still relevant for freeipa 4.4.0 and Ubuntu 16.04 (Lubuntu). I got here from ddg search `ubuntu freeipa mkhomedir`. So far I haven't needed any of these other manual steps.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 you shouldn't need to customize the config file, but you _do_ need to run `sudo pam-auth-update` for it to become active.